# Node js Eventemitter not fireing

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, electron, event-handling

I have the Problem, that my Eventemitter is not fireing. I already googled the Problem and it seems like my order of the code is wrong.. or at least thats my guess. Anyways, no matter how I put the Order of creating the **client.js** class, it's not triggering.

FYI creating a electron app that is communicating with a server over TCP/IP. When the clients connection status is changing, the "connection"-event should trigger to tell the frontend to change. Other events like "error" are working.

I dont know if this is enough code for you, just tell me if you need more.

client.js

```js
class Client extends events.EventEmitter {
  constructor(HOST, PORT){
    // setting up the client..
    super();
    this.host = HOST;
    this.port = PORT;
    // and so on...
    this.client = new net.Socket();
    // othere eventlisteres...
    this.client.on("connect", this.connectEventHandler);
  }
  connectEventHandler() {
    try {
      this.status = "connected"; // I can check the status from main
      this.tryReconnecting = false; // other logic of the client class
      this.emit("connection"); // this is the event (not working)
      console.log("connection status should be triggered"); // this console.log is working
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      this.emit("error", error);
    }
  }
}
```

main.js

```js
// creating the client
const client = new Client(process.env.SERVER, process.env.PORT);

// when the app is ready, client is told to connect to the server
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow();
  app.on("activate", function () {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow();
  });
  client.connect();
});

// the error event is working perfectly, event when I call it in the connectEventHandler
client.on("error", (message) => {
  console.log("error event triggered");
  dialog.showMessageBoxSync(mainWindow, {
    title: "Fehler",
    message: message,
  });
});

// this part is not working
client.on("connection", () => {
  console.log("new client status: " + client.status);
  mainWindow.webContents.send("client-status", client.status);
});
```

Even when I call the error event instead of the connection event, the error is displayed in my app:

```js
// code from client.js
connectEventHandler() {
  try {
    this.status = "connected"; // I can check the status from main
    this.tryReconnecting = false; // other logic of the client class

    // this part is getting ignored
    this.emit("connection");

    // this part is executed
    this.emit("error", "this is a test error");

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    this.emit("error", error);
  }
}
```

the Response from the last bit of code (connectEventHandler):

[image: Response from frontend in "connectEventHandler"]

What is going on here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was the ConnectEventHandler, after putting the logic of this function into the constructor of the client, every event is getting triggered properly.